# Using Boost statechart, how can I transition to a state unconditionally?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-statechart

I have a state `A` that I would like to transition to its next state `B` unconditionally, once the constructor of `A` has completed. Is this possible?

I tried posting an event from the constructor, which does not work, even though it compiles. Thanks.

**Edit:** Here is what I've tried so far:

```
struct A : sc::simple_state< A, Active >
{
    public:
        typedef sc::custom_reaction< EventDoneA > reactions;
        A()
        {
            std::cout << "Inside of A()" << std::endl;
            post_event( EventDoneA() );
        }

        sc::result react( const EventDoneA & )
        {
            return transit< B >();
        }
};
```

This yields the following runtime assertion failure:

```
Assertion failed: get_pointer( pContext_ ) != 0, file /includ
e/boost/statechart/simple_state.hpp, line 459
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've updated my OP with my solution, here it is so I can close the question.

The problem is that you cannot inherit from `simple_state` to achieve the desired transition, you must inherit from `state`, which then requires that you modify the constructor accordingly.

```
struct A : sc::state< A, Active >
{
    public:
        typedef sc::custom_reaction< EventDoneA > reactions;
        A( my_context ctx ) : my_base( ctx )
        {
            std::cout << "Inside of A()" << std::endl;
            post_event( EventDoneA() );
        }

        sc::result react( const EventDoneA & )
        {
            return transit< B >();
        }
};
```

Comment: You should not update the question with the correct answer, just answer the question.  People like to see the original issue.

Comment: @GregorBrandt - My mistake, I've reverted the OP to my original question (I think), which should fix everything. Thanks!

Comment: So, basically, you forgot the context? It always helps to explicitly point out what corrections where made.

Comment: @Xeo Good point! The context is necessary because I was incorrectly inheriting from `simple_state`, and you need to inherit from `state`.